# How to sort only the row names of a data frame in alphabetical order?

Tags: r, dataframe

I don't know how to sort only the rownames of a dataframe in alphabetical order.

For example below.

```
 mtcars 
               mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt ... 
Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.62 ... 
Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.88 ... 
Datsun 710    22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.32 ...
```

My end goal is for it to look like this

```
Datsun 710
Mazda RX4
Mazda RX4 Wag
...
```

and not like

```
Datsun 710    22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.32 ...
  Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.62 ... 
Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.88 ...
```

Thanks

Comment: you mean sth like this `sort(rownames(mtcars))`?

Comment: yes, thank you! except i substituted the 'mtcars' for 'df' .and how can i shorten it to the first 20 since it gives me a long list?

Comment: You mean then like `sort(rownames(mtcars))[1:20]`?